# How do I open and write to a file with the name taken from a string in C++?

Tags: c++

While making a project i was trying to do this simple task
1.Making the file opening based on an if situation
2.Letting the user enter a name of a .txt file
3.combining the name given by the user and the .txt to make a simple file name
Example:
"test"".txt"
4.Letting the user pass in information and writing it to a file

here's the code if you are confused

```
     if (wordChoose=="ofile")
    {
                    cout <<("      File Name?")<< endl;
                    string fileNaming;
                    cin >> fileNaming;
            
                    FILE *f=fopen((fileNaming+".txt").c_str());
            
                    const char *text;
                    cin >> *text;
                    fprintf(text);
            
            `by the way, this is for a school project`
                    system ("pause");
                    return 0;
    }
```

edit:i'll give the whole code, good luck

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string inputComm;

int PCOS()
{
    string accountSettings;
    cin >> inputComm;
    
    if (inputComm=="comp.start")
    {
        cout <<("               Pear .P.C.O.S. Computer System \n")<< endl;
        
        cout <<("     Main Menu:")<< endl;
    cout <<("     1<        SETTINGS")<< endl;
    cout <<("     2<        APPLICATIONS")<< endl;
    cout <<("     3<        RADIO NETWORKS")<< endl;
    cout <<("     4<        CREDITS")<< endl;
    
    string menuChoose;
    
    cin >> menuChoose;
    
    if(menuChoose=="pea.app")
    {
        cout <<("     Applications:")<< endl;
        cout <<("     1<           CALCULATOR")<< endl;
        cout <<("     2<           FMAKE DOCUMENT APPLICATION")<< endl;
        cout <<("     3<           HUCKY")<< endl;
        
        string appChoose;
        
        cin >> appChoose;
        
        if (appChoose=="app.fmake")
        {
            cout <<("      Fmake Document Application:")<< endl;
            cout <<("      1<                        MAKE FILE")<< endl;
            cout <<("      2<                        OPEN FILE")<< endl;
            
            string wordChoose;
            cin >> wordChoose;
            
            if (wordChoose=="fmake.ofile");
            {
                cout <<("      File Name?")<< endl;
                string fileNaming;
                cin >> fileNaming;
                
                FILE *f=fopen((fileNaming+".txt").c_str());
                
                const char *text;
                cin >> *text;
                fprintf(text);
                
                
                system ("pause");
                return 0;
            }
            
            if (wordChoose=="fmake.mfile")
            {
                cout <<("      What is the name of the file?")<< endl;
                string fileName;
                cin >> fileName;
                
                fstream ((fileName+".txt").c_str());
                
                cout <<("      To continue, restart the os.")<< endl;
                system ("pause");
                return 0;
            }       
        }
        
        if(appChoose=="app.calc")
        {
            cout <<("     Calculator:")<< endl;
            cout <<("     1<         ADDITION")<< endl;
            cout <<("     2<         SUBTRACTION")<< endl;
            cout <<("     3<         MULTIPLICATION")<< endl;
            cout <<("     4<         DIVISION")<< endl;
            
            string equationType;
            
            cin >> equationType;
            
            if (equationType=="calc.div")
            {
                cout <<("      Enter the first number")<< endl;
                
                double firstDIVnumber;
                cin >> firstDIVnumber;
                
                cout <<("      Go on")<< endl;
                
                double secondDIVnumber;
                cin >> secondDIVnumber;
                
                double sumDIV=firstDIVnumber / secondDIVnumber;
                cout << sumDIV;
                cout <<("      To continue, restart the os")<< endl;
                system("pause");
                return 0;
            }
            
            if (equationType=="calc.mtt")
            {
                cout <<("      Enter the first number")<< endl;
                
                double firstMTTnumber;
                cin >> firstMTTnumber;
                
                cout <<("      Go on")<< endl;
                
                double secondMTTnumber;
                cin >> secondMTTnumber;
                
                double sumMTT=firstMTTnumber*secondMTTnumber;
                cout << sumMTT;
                cout <<("      To continue, restart the os")<< endl;
                system ("pause");
                return 0;
            }
            
            if (equationType=="calc.stt")
            {
                cout <<("      Enter the first number")<< endl;
                
                double firstSTTnumber;
                cin >> firstSTTnumber;
                
                cout <<("      Go on")<< endl;
                
                double secondSTTnumber;
                cin >> secondSTTnumber;
                
                double sumSTT=firstSTTnumber-secondSTTnumber;
                cout << sumSTT;
                cout <<("      To continue, restart the os")<< endl;
                system ("pause");
                return 0;
            }
            
            if(equationType=="calc.add")
            {
                cout <<("      Enter the first number")<< endl;
                
                double firstADDnumber;
                cin >> firstADDnumber;
                
                double secondADDnumber;
                cin >> secondADDnumber;
                
                double sumADD=firstADDnumber+secondADDnumber;
                cout << sumADD;
                cout <<("     To continue, restart the os")<< endl;
                system ("pause");
                return 0;   
            }
        } 
    }
    
    if(menuChoose=="pea.stt")
    {
        cout <<("     Settings:")<< endl;
        cout <<("     1<       ACCOUNTS")<< endl;
        cout <<("     2<       SHUT DOWN")<< endl;
        
        string settingOptions;
        cin >> settingOptions;
        
        if (settingOptions=="stt.acc")
        {
            cout <<("     Accounts:")<< endl;
            cout <<("     1<       CREATE ACCOUNT")<< endl;
            cout <<("     2<       DELETE ACCOUNT")<< endl;
            
            string accountSettings;
            
            cin >> accountSettings;
            if(accountSettings=="acc.cac")
            {
                cout <<("Create your name")<< endl;
                string accname;
                
                cin >> accname;
                
                cout <<("Type the password")<< endl;
                string accpassword;
                
                cin >> accpassword;
                
                cout <<("Settings Saved, restart the os to continue")<< endl;
            }
            
            if(accountSettings=="acc.del")
            {
                cout <<("          Acount deleted")<< endl;
            }
        }
        if(settingOptions=="stt.shutd")
        {
            cout <<("          Shutting down")<< endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    }
    else
    {
        char errM[]="Unable to read written text";
        cerr <<("ERROR_MESSAGE:")<< errM << endl;
        cout <<("Please restart the device and write the right command")<< endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    PCOS();
}
```

Comment: `cin >> *text;` invokes undefined behavior. You haven't initialized `text` to point to any valid memory. Why aren't you simply using another `std::string` for `text`?

Comment: Have you checked out a tutorial like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)?  Go slow, try to understand as much as you can, play with and manipulate the examples, follow links if something is unfamiliar...

Answer (score -1):

```
cout << "      File Name?" << endl;
string fileNaming;
cin >> fileNaming;
```

3. combine name by user with .txt

```
fileNaming +=".txt";
std::fstream fileio(fileNaming);
if (fileio.is_open())
{
    //do stuff
}
```

4 : user writes to file : in place of `//do stuff`

```
std::string userStr;
cin >> userStr;
fileio << userStr;
```

After you edited your question with code, it looks like you want to call a function based on user input. I'd recommend using a map of functions :
using your code :

```
cout <<("     Applications:")<< endl;
        cout <<("     1<           CALCULATOR")<< endl;
        cout <<("     2<           FMAKE DOCUMENT APPLICATION")<< endl;
        cout <<("     3<           HUCKY")<< endl;
        
        string appChoose;        
        cin >> appChoose;
```

you create a map, give a string, this map will call a function.

```
void Calculator () {
//do stuff
}
typedef void (*pfunc)();
map<string, pfunc> funcMap; 
//"app.calc" is whatever string the user will later type
funcMap["app.calc"] = Calculator; //assign functions to the map this way
//assigne other functions here
```

call the function :

```
pfunc foo = funcMap[appChoose];
(*foo)(); //call function
```

Comment: I didn't know that in a minute i can get a few people answering my question, thanks alot, the comments dont seem too bad as they help me at least a little, thank you fellow users!

Comment: @DanielKyle I've added code to match your edited question, this shows you how to do what you want, you're the one who will have to do the coding though